# Trying to execute a BiqQuery Stored Procedure from a Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have the following code in Google Cloud Function. The cloud function is written in.NET 6 C#

```
var testsku = 1414;

var parameters = new BigQueryParameter[]
{
     new BigQueryParameter("skuId", BigQueryDbType.Int64, testsku),
};

BigQueryClient client = BigQueryClient.Create(projectID);
string query = @"CALL 'xxxxxxx.xxxxxx.fraudskus'()";
BigQueryJob job = client.CreateQueryJob(
     sql: query,
     parameters: parameters,
    options: new QueryOptions { UseQueryCache = false });
// Wait for the job to complete.
job.PollUntilCompleted();
// Display the results
int numOrders = 0;
foreach (BigQueryRow row in client.GetQueryResults(job.Reference))
{
     numOrders++;
}
message = "Num of rows = " + numOrders;
```

The stored procedure runs fine in BIGQUERY and  outputs the right results, but I am getting errors on the call to the stored procedure as follows.

```
"The service bigquery has thrown an exception.
No HttpStatusCode was specified.
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Job unique-moon-366800/US/job_24e29215_e011_4d66_a2c4_bbf5640d5cc6 contained 2 error(s). First error message: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'unique-moon-366800.ecommerce_fraud_ds.fraudskus' at [1:6] [0]
Errors [
    Message[Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'xxxx.xxxxx.fraudskus' at [1:6]] Location[query - ] Reason[invalidQuery] Domain[]
    Message[Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'xxxx.xxxxx.fraudskus' at [1:6]] Location[query - ] Reason[invalidQuery] Domain[]
]

Google.GoogleApiException: The service bigquery has thrown an exception. No HttpStatusCode was specified. Job xxxxxxx/US/job_24e29215_e011_4d66_a2c4_bbf5640d5cc6 contained 2 error(s). First error message: Syntax error: Unexpected string literal 'unique-moon-366800.ecommerce_fraud_ds.fraudskus' at [1:6]
   at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryJob.ThrowOnFatalError()
   at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryJob.GetQueryDestinationTable()
   at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryJob.GetQueryResults(GetQueryResultsOptions options)
   at Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2.BigQueryClientImpl.GetQueryResults(JobReference jobReference, GetQueryResultsOptions options)
   at SimpleHttpFunction.Function.HandleAsync(HttpContext context) in /workspace/Function.cs:line 196
   at Google.Cloud.Functions.Hosting.HostingInternals.Execute(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)"
```

I can get the results I expect if I use sql SELECT, but not if I try to call the stored procedure.

Comment: Use anti-quote ` ` ` instead of simple quote `'` around your procedure name

Comment: Yep, that fixed. Appreciate the answer.